# How can I change my virtual environment's pyvenv.cfg file's home?

Tags: python, windows, mingw, python-venv, msys

I need to create a virtual environment which is something I am familiar with. However, I can't activate it since I have no "Scripts" folder inside my venv. I traced the problem to the pyvenv.cfg file, which has this listed as my home:

C:\msys64\mingw64\bin

I read online that some people have issues when this is listed as their "home" but I can't seem to know how to change it.
In previous projects where the venv worked correctly, the home is listed as:

C:\Users\zaida\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0

I tried to change the path environment variables but no luck and I also don't really know what I'm doing there.

I'd appreciate any pointers.

Thanks

Comment: Recreate the virtual environment from scratch. -- Seems like you have more than one Python interpreter (which is okay). Make sure to use the correct Python interpreter explicitly. -- Double check that `python` points to the Python interpreter you actually want to use then run `python -m venv ...` as usual. In case of doubt you can call the full path explicitly `path/to/python -m venv ...`. -- I would recommend against modifying the `pyvenv.cfg` file.